# iTunes lookup API return old data in my APP

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, lookup, itunes-store

My APP check update by comparing local version and remote version returned by iTunes lookup API. But the API still return old version after new version has released.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/lookup?bundleId=com.xxx.xxxx

This API return new version(4.9) if I request through browser, but return old version(4.8.1) in APP.

Anybody help? Thanks.

```
- (void)updateAppInfo

{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //first check iTunes
    NSString *iTunesServiceURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/lookup"];
    iTunesServiceURL = [iTunesServiceURL stringByAppendingFormat:@"?bundleId=%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
    NSLog(@"iRate is checking %@ to retrieve the App Store details...", iTunesServiceURL);

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesServiceURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSInteger statusCode = ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statusCode;
    if (data && statusCode == 200)
    {
        //in case error is garbage...
        error = nil;
        id json = nil;
        if ([NSJSONSerialization class])
        {
            json = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)0 error:&error][@"results"] lastObject];
        }
        else
        {
            //convert to string
            json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        }

        if (!error)
        {
            self.appStoreId = [self valueForKey:@"trackId" inJSON:json];
            self.latestVersion = [self valueForKey:@"version" inJSON:json];
            self.releaseNote = [self valueForKey:@"releaseNotes" inJSON:json];
        }
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: I've had a new version released yesterday and it is still not available in the AppStore. Maybe your new version is Ready For Sale on iTunesConnect but not yet available in the AppStore?

Comment: It may take sometime for the data to reflect in all systems, I suggest you to wait for sometime.

Comment: @rckoenes nope, I can download new version in the AppStore

Comment: Like @satheeshwaran says it might take some time for the changes to show up everywhere. How long has it been since you the app has the status ready for sale?

Comment: @rckoenes about 12 hours

Comment: Just wait, 12 hours is to short.

Comment: Hi! I am experiencing exactly the same issue. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @rckoenes 12 hours is said to be short, but it works well on a web browser. Why doesn't it only work on the app?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I was also facing same issue but in my case I was using http (e.g. http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.xxx.xxxx) so not getting latest app version. Then I replaced **http to https** (https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.xxx.xxxx) after that its working for me.

**Update -** Our team sent mail to apple developers and ask why https is working and http is not working and got reply from apple team. He told **"In general, there is a 24 hours delay for updated app information to go from App Store Connect to the public."**

For more information see their email reply-[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Is https resolved the issue?

Comment: You said there's a 24 hour delay, but what's interesting is that there's no problem with browsing with a web browser. This problem happens with the app.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also having the same issue now. I talked to another developer and he came into the conclusion that it could be a CDN issue. (Content delivery network)

- When I connect to our wifi, the response is outdated.
- When I connect to my 4G data, the response is updated.

Comment: This is not it. I changed the USIM and tried it on, but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. It has two steps to resolve this issue.

I was using **http**://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId="YOUR BUNDLE ID" not the **https**.

Step #1: Please ensure that you are using **https** not the **http** because it will not give you the updated version number.
First i uploaded my app with version **1.8.0** then version **1.9.0** then version **1.9.1**. When i used **http** it was always showing me 1.8.0 even the app on app store had the version **1.9.1**. So, just use **https** for future.

Step #2: After uploading the latest version please wait for 24 hours in order to get the latest version on **https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId="YOUR BUNDLE ID"**. I was getting version **1.9.0** even though the app was live with version **1.9.1** within 24 hours. I waited for 24 hours and then it started giving me the correct version and then i was able to force update my app by version checking.

Answer (score 0):

Not all apps are available in all countries. In your URL, looking for it in the US store. Remove **/us/** and try.

For more details: [iTunes search API won't show existing app info](https://discussions.apple.com/message/28423790#28423790)

Answer (score 0):

Ok @Yunnosch
currently not able to fetch application info in JSON format from this url

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId="YOUR BUNDLE ID".

Therefore we need to change URL with this

New URL will https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id="Your Bundle id"

This is just informing new latest url in comment.

Comment: Please make more obvious the additional insight your post contributes, especially in comparison to the answer by Syed Faizan Ahmed.