# itunes lookup API returns old data in APP not through browser

Tags: ios, itunes

I have exactly same problem in

[iTunes lookup API return old data in my APP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226752/itunes-lookup-api-return-old-data-in-my-app)

API: https://itunes.apple.com/kr/lookup?bundleId=com.xxx.xxxx

if I request through browser it returns new version but when I check it in my APP, it returns old version.

someone said that it could be CDN issue but when I updated APP before, it returned new version.

```
- (NSString *)appVersionInfo{NSString *appVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]; 
return appVersion;}

- (BOOL)compareSameAppVersion{
   NSString *thisAppVersion = [self appVersionInfo];
   NSString *currentAppVersion = nil;
   NSDictionary *infoDic = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
  NSString *appId = infoDic[@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:URL_APP_STORE_APTNER_BUNDLE, appId]];
   NSLog(@"%@",url);
   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
   NSDictionary *lookup = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
   if([lookup[@"resultCount"] integerValue] == 1){
   currentAppVersion = lookup[@"results"][0][@"version"];
   
   NSLog(@"AppStoreVersion : %@, thisAppVersion : %@", currentAppVersion, thisAppVersion);
   
   if([currentAppVersion isEqualToString:thisAppVersion]){
       NSLog(@"AppStoreVersion : %@, thisAppVersion : %@", currentAppVersion, thisAppVersion);
       return YES;
   }
   }else{
       return NO;
   }
  return NO;
}
```

the result is

> AppStoreVersion : 1.0.5(which is old)
> thisAppVersion : 1.0.6(which is new and updated in app store already)

Anyone help?

Comment: Did you have any explanation/solution for this?

Comment: If I am not wrong, this question is duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226752/itunes-lookup-api-return-old-data-in-my-app